# is it possible to share an nfs share?

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs

I have multiple nfs  shares from multiple sources, I would like to centralize all shares to re-dispatch them... I've tried but I can't see the content of a shara from the center of operations... Can it be possible or not?
thanks
So to draw you a picture:

NAS nfs share->                }
RAID linux machine nfs share-> }debian nfs HQ -> multiple linux child

Comment: "debian nfs hq"? what is that?  And if these are in the same network: then of course you can share them. It is the whole idea of network shares :P

Comment: re-read my message, since you didn't understand

Comment: @vigilian You want to create a NAS raid ? as in a RAID 0

Comment: @Neil no.
As I said we have multiple nfs shares from different sources so different computers.We don't want to add 15 lines to each fstab in each computer or VM from this local network. So I want to centralize all the nfs shares, not physically-> logically, so just a computer to dispatch one big nfs share.
So I don't want to build a new computer with all the physical disks! I want to link all the nfs shares to one computer which would be something like a control computer which would do one export of all the nfs shares from one folder and so control the access of all the nfs shares in one place

Comment: I don't understand where the problem of comprehension is. Did you never have something like 5-15 nfs shares from different sources like different NASs and different computer with RAID and to control them in one place and make one big share for the whole LAN?

Comment: Yes someing like that. But nas shares can't  be just joined up to make one big one. You will have to use loop devices. Don't know how you can avoid not having 15 lines in fstab when you have more than 15 shares

Comment: okey, do you know what's the problem exactly? the permissions calculus?

Comment: so it is not possible to do nfs over nfs?

Answer (score 0):

@Rinzwind so you didn't understand what I said :

the point here is to put all the nfs share of the network in one point then to dispatch them!
so Debian nfs HQ will be the system where all the nfs shares will be re-unite into one.

To put it simply, I don't want 15 lines in the /etc/fstab of each machine which need the nfs share and as I stated, we have multiple nfs shares from multiple sources!!!!!